# laravel query builder having two fields

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder, having

How I can get data with use HAVING by two custom fields?

```
->having('timeFrom', '<', 'timeTo')
```

return HAVING `timeFrom` < 'timeTo'

PS: DB::raw() does not help.

Comment: Do you have a working sql query?

Comment: Is there any issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
->havingRaw('timeFrom', '<', 'timeTo')
```

**Updated Answer**

->where('timeFrom', '<', DB::raw('timeTo'))

I think this solve your problem

Comment: This isn't how you'd use `havingRaw`.

Comment: It's not work, I get empty result, though native sql query return over 100 items.

Comment: @user4301988 Or are you checked with simple where condition like:
`->where('timeFrom', '<', 'timeTo')` **OR** `->whereDate('timeFrom', '<', 'timeTo')`  **OR** `->whereDate('timeFrom', '<', DB::raw('timeTo'))`

Comment: All 3 variants return error. Here it is necessary to use having.